# create a variable name from a string.. php

Tags: php

Generally I pass an array of parameters to my functions.

```
function do_something($parameters) {}
```

To access those parameters I have to use: `$parameters['param1']`

What I would like to do, is run some sort of logic inside  this function on those parameters that converts that array into normal variables. My main reasons is just that sometimes I have to pass a whole load of parameters and having to type $parameters['..'] is a pain.

```
foreach($parameters as $key=>$paremeter) {
    "$key" = $parameter;
}
```

I thought that might work.. but no cigar!

Comment: I can see why -> $paremeter :-)

Comment: Not to mention that you're assigning it to a literal string (which isn't possible)...  `$$key = ` would work, but not `"$key" = `...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`extract()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
function do_something($parameters) {
    extract($parameters);

    // Do stuff; for example, echo one of the parameters
    if (isset($param1)) {
        echo "param1 = $param1";
    }
}

do_something(array('param1' => 'foo'));
```

Comment: And you can add "defaults" by doing something like `extract($parameters + array('param1' => null, 'param2' => null))`...  One other thing though.  If you're going to directly push `$parameters` to `extract`, I'd suggest adding an `array` type hint `function do_something(array $parameters)` to prevent trying to `extract` some other type...

Comment: Use of extract() specially if it's outside a function or the parameters come from user input is a great security risk.

Answer (score 3):

Try `$$key=$parameter`.

Comment: That works too, but `extract($parameter)` probably is easier.

Comment: I agree, but I figured the OP might want to know what was wrong with the specific approach he was using.

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the variables from array using [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

> Import variables into the current
>   symbol table from an array

```
extract($parameters);
```

Now you can access the variables directly eg `$var` which are keys present in the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `extract` function.  This is what you want.

```
$array = array('a'=>'dog', 'b'=>'cat');
extract($array);
echo $a; //'dog'
echo $b; //'cat'
```